# py3k: mapping dictionary (string->number) into list (of strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume we have dictionary that translates strings into numbers.

How to reverse it into list ?
Let assume, we can fill not mapped numbers with empty string `''`.

Here example how it works:

```
>>> dic_into_list({'x':0, 'z':2, 'w':3})
['x', '', 'z', 'w']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {'x':0, 'z':2, 'w':3}
lst = [""] * (max(d.values()) + 1)
for k, v in d.items():
    lst[v] = k
print(lst)
```

prints

```
['x', '', 'z', 'w']
```

Comment: While both are technically O(max(d.values) + 1) time complexity, this method should be faster than mine. List multiplication is simpler than dictionary inversion, and it should be faster to iterate over a dictionary and index a list than iterate over a list and do dictionary lookups. I like the logic of my version better, as it mirrors how I'd think about the problem if I wasn't bound by the limits of the data types.

Comment: @agf I agree with you. Even it seems faster, thanks for your answer, it's good for comparison of different solutions :). It's always good to have alternative cause in slightly different case , yours might be better for modyfication.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to flip the `dict` and then iterate up to the maximum value (now key) in the `dict`:

```
original = {'x':0, 'z':2, 'w':3}
d = dict((v, k) for k, v in original.iteritems())
print [d.get(i, '') for i in range(max(d) + 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I share my current solution: (I look for shorter and cleared implementation in other posts):

```
def dic_into_list(dic):
    maxindex = max([v for i,v in dic.items()])
    dicrev = {num:name for name,num in dic.items()}
    l=[]
    for i in range(0,maxindex+1):
        if i in dicrev:
            l.append(dicrev[i])
        else:
            l.append('')
    return l
```

Comment: @poke Not necessarily; it is after all a valid answer to the question, and he could have marked it as accepted if no one else came up with a better answer.